# How to omit positional argument with string format?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How will I omit last positional argument with string format ?

Consider below. Sometime I am not interested in passing the last positional argument. As last argument value is not there. It`s an optional argument.

```
message = """ {name} {age}"""
message.format(name='sameer')   # This will give me error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot avoid it, but an empty string will do:

```
message = """ {name} {age}"""
message.format(name='sameer', age='')
```

If you want get fancy, you can write function that replaces all not given keyword arguments with empty strings:

```
from string import Formatter

def my_format(msg, **kwargs):
    defaults = {x[1]: '' for x in Formatter().parse(msg)}
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return msg.format(**defaults)

message = """Person: {name} {age}"""
print(my_format(message, name='sameer', age=30)) 
print(my_format(message, name='sameer')) 
print(my_format(message))
```

Output:

```
Person: sameer 30
Person: sameer 
Person:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it empty, then Mike Müller's answer is the right one.

If you want to leave the slot in the string, just replace the single braces with double ones:

```
>>> message = """ {name} {{age}}"""
>>> message.format(name='sameer')
' sameer {age}'
```

You could then fill that slot later.